# Parse a XAML positions string into a list of Point3D

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to find the most elegant way to convert a string to a list of points.

The source is an XAML file. Here is an exemple of the list of points :

> Positions="-25,5,0 -25,5,5 25,5,0 25,5,5 25,5,0 25,5,5 25,10,0 25,10,5
> 25,10,0 25,10,5 -25,10,0 -25,10,5 -25,10,0 -25,10,5 -25,5,0 -25,5,5
> -25,5,0 25,5,0 25,10,0 -25,10,0 -25,5,5 25,5,5 25,10,5 -25,10,5"

I want to convert it to a list of Point3D :

```
List<Point3D> Positions
```

I know the two basic tools i need are Point3D.Parse() and String.Split(), but my knowledge of linq is not sufficient to do this elegantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be enough for what you need

```cs
List<Point3D> positions = positionsString
    .Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(p => Point3D.Parse(p))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, just asking the question made me find the answer :

```
List<Point3D> Positions= PositionsString.Value.Split(' ')
                                 .Select(Point3D.Parse)
                                 .ToList();
```

Comment: It should be sufficient to write: `.Select(Point3D.Parse);` in the last section.